# Rails: confused with blocks helper and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following functions on a helper

```
#soround with a div
def bigDiv &block
  render "test/big_div", block: block
end
```

the _big_div_partial is:

```
<div>
<%= block.call()%>
</div>
```

And I use the following in a html.erb page

```
<%= bigDiv do %>
    text
<% end %>
```

The output is:

```
text
text
```

where I expeted

```
text
```

Why is it writing text two times?

Answer (score 1):

It is, beacuse you're writing into buffer twice. First, the result of block `<%= block.call %>` and then output of:

```
<%= bigDiv do %>
    text
<% end %>
```

Drop `=` from `<%= block.call %>`